# How to use KSOAP fault-messages

Tags: android, ksoap2, fault

I'm invoking a Java-based web-service with KSOAP2 for Android, and I would like to know how I can make use of the KSOAP fault-messages.

For example: The response-dump looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body><soap:Fault>
   <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>SQL Error</faultstring>
   <detail>
    <ns2:SQLException xmlns:ns2="http://...">
    <SQLError>[PreferenceException]Error compiling sql-expression==============================Column : [NAME] doesn't exist</SQLError>
    <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
    </ns2:SQLException>
   </detail>
  </soap:Fault>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I forward the "[Name] doesn't exit"-error to the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

envelope.getResponse will throw a SoapFault exception that you just catch and then use getMessage to bring up a toast or whatever you want to do.